# Smartgwt SELECT ALL functionality

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Need help regarding.selectall functionality. I have created a form.

```
DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();  
final SelectItem category = new SelectItem("category", "Employee Category");  
category.setMultiple(true);  
category.setValueMap("Direct","InDirect","ALL");  
form.setFields(category);
```

If i select 'ALL' all three items in picklist should also be selected.if i deselect 'ALL' all three items should be deseleted. need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try out the following:

```
boolean isAllSelected = false; // global variable
SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem("category", "Employee Category");
selectItem.setMultiple(true);
selectItem.setMultipleAppearance(MultipleAppearance.PICKLIST);
selectItem.setValueMap("Direct","InDirect","ALL");
selectItem.addChangedHandler(new ChangedHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged(ChangedEvent event) {
        if (event.getValue() != null) {
            if (event.getValue().toString().contains("ALL")) {
                if (!isAllSelected) {
                    selectItem.setValues("Direct","InDirect", "ALL");
                    isAllSelected = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (isAllSelected) {
                    selectItem.clearValue();
                }
                isAllSelected = false;
            }
        } else {
            isAllSelected = false;
        }
    }
});

DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
form.setSize("800px", "400px");
form.setFields(selectItem);
form.draw();
```

Comment: hi RAS thank you for your answer .the issue is solved.please can you also help me in setting data fetched dynamically . i am fetching data from database using fetchdata(). how to set the data dynamically if ALL is selected

Comment: @SubodhK What do you mean by setting data dynamically? Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: hi , i am fetching data from database for SelectItem() selectItem = new SelectItem(); selectItem.epsId.addClickHandler({selectItem.fetchData();{).i am catching all the data that is fetched into a list using selectItem.dataArrivedHandler().i am trying to set the values of selectItem if ALL is selected using the list got from dataArrivedHandler().

   }
  });